# Not able to import ggplot in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, visualization, python-ggplot

I have Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 both python 2.7 and python 3.5 installed.
I have installed ggplot in python 3.5 but not able to import it.

I am getting `ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'.`

Am I missing something? As far as I know `StringIO` module has been merged in `io` module in python 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, some files have not been fully converted for python3.

Open file `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ggplot/ggplot.py` and change

`import StringIO`

to this

`from io import StringIO`

I am not getting any error now but there could be some other files where python2 codes needs to be converted to work in python3.